# How to split the columns into multiple columns

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(did = c(216L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 
221L, 214L, 214L, 214L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 214L, 
221L, 221L, 221L, 221L, 205L, 221L, 221L), fruid = c(1007L, 1697L, 
1697L, 1698L, 1697L, 1697L, 1697L, 1697L, 2074L, 2074L, 2074L, 
2087L, 2087L, 2087L, 2087L, 2087L, 2087L, 2074L, 2087L, 2087L, 
3884L, 3884L, 2249L, 2087L, 1461L), hhid = c(89L, 5258L, 5256L, 
5192L, 5301L, 5289L, 5296L, 5255L, 16413L, 8911L, 21550L, 5683L, 
12001L, 5761L, 5667L, 5682L, 11988L, 21553L, 11996L, 11986L, 
12158L, 12191L, 10367L, 5676L, 1130L), isenterprise = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), sale = c(11, 1750, 0, 4000, 0, 0, 
2450, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1600, 0, 0
), purchase = c(255, 750, 0, 3838, 0, 0, 1700, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cash = c(99, 520, 0, 
1150, 0, 0, 1585, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2500, 0, 0), asset = c(11, 1750, 0, 4000, 0, 0, 2450, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1600, 0, 0), islivestock = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), lstype = c("0", "0", "Goatry", 
"0", "Goatry", "Goatry", "0", "Goatry", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), 
    isagriculture = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), tsavings = c(5L, 1120L, 1200L, 2150L, 2700L, 4220L, 400L, 
    400L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 840L, 0L, 0L), month_year = c("Dec - 2019", "Dec - 2019", 
    "Dec - 2019", "Dec - 2019", "Dec - 2019", "Dec - 2019", "Dec - 2019", 
    "Dec - 2019", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", 
    "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", 
    "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", 
    "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020", "Jan - 2020")), row.names = c(NA, 
25L), class = "data.frame")
```

So the output expected is like this:
did  fruid  month_year  hhid_count isenterprise_count t_sale  t_purchase t_cash t_asset t_saving
islivestock_count  t_sale  t_purchase t_cash t_asset t_saving  isagriculture_count  t_sale  t_purchase t_cash t_asset t_saving.

To explain the output,I want to count hhid on the basis of month_year and same would be for isenterprise,is livestock and isagriculture.Other method that I have tried is to split it with columnnames as did fruid month_year hhid_count isenterprise t_sale t_purchase t_cash t_asset tsaving.
And islivestock and isagriculture in other two.So total of 3 data frames.but I require it in a single dataframe as mentioned in expected output.

Comment: Do you want to also count hhid on the basis of isnterprise (etc.) or do you want to also count isenterprise (etc.) on the basisof month_year?

Comment: hhid_count would be month_year and isenterprise(etc) would be counted by fruid.So basically using group_by(did,fruid,month_year,hhid)